# Размещение скрытых ссылок

Tags: html, ссылки

Есть возможность разместить ссылку на свой сайт на многих сайтах. Но нужно сделать это, как можно незаметнее может даже, чтобы внешней части у ссылки вообще не было... какие варианты есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
<a href='http://mysite.ru'>&nbsp</a>
```

2)

```
<body onclick="window.location = 'http://mysite.ru'">
```

3)

```
$('body').click(function(){
window.location = 'http://mysite.ru';
});
```

Убивать надо всех, кто размещает скрытые ссылки.

Comment: откуда столько негатива?

Comment: Нет нужды прятать ссылку, если она размещена законно. Наоборот, надо ее описать и показать. Все остальное - спам. Вот и негатив.

Comment: можно поинтересоваться, как вы сделаете подобное(метод 2 и 3) на стороннем сайте?

Comment: Третье - элементарно: есть куча сайтов, проверку на тэги которых можно обмануть.  
Второе - сложнее, но тоже можно, если, по каким-то причинам, вам дали к нему доступ. Был у нас такой тип.

Answer (score 2):

Делать текст ссылки в виде "." или текст цветом фона. Но за такие дела можно попасть в баню яндекса.

Comment: за что конкретно? за размещение ссылок без текста?

Comment: Без текста, скрытый текст - т.е. текст цветом фона и т.п. Это все негативно отражается на индексации, вплоть до бана.

Answer (score 2):

Можно прописать ссылку с прозрачностью, как это сделано, например, на http://studioad.ru/. Присмотритесь, там есть ссылки на pr-cy и liveinternet, но в глаза они не бросаются.

Comment: кстати классно сделано, еле нашел )))

Answer (score 0):

Обычно умные люди закрывают от индексации внешние ссылки со своих форумов, например, потому, если Вы влепите в подпись (или еще куда) ссылку, которой не будет видно - Вы просто зря потратите время в большинстве случаев, да и поисковики такие ссылки в лучшем случае просто проигнорируют, в худшем дадут бан сайту..